# Would an underground species of humanoids need a large landmass to make their cities or could they get by with having mostly islands?

Tags: civilization, construction

So I have this species of small humanoids called pinokiins(Pee-no-key-inn) that for the most part live in underground structures called bunktresses(bunker+fortress). Most of them are smaller, like made the size of a large highschool, but some get pretty big, like the size of a state or small country. Sometimes they even make tunnels connecting bunktresses to each other. Anyway, what I am trying to ask is if they would need a large landmass to build a lot of their bunktresses in or could they build them if they lived on islands since I am assuming that the water above the tunnels would make it alot harder to do. FYI, the world they live on, or rather in, is called Pinokia(Pee-no-key-ah/named after the top inhabitants) and is pretty much Earth-like barring the landmasses.

Comment: Would you be able to tell us anything about their technology level, the sort of industrial infrastructure they have and the distances between islands. It's also difficult to know unless we have an idea how advanced their geological sciences are, and the type of rocks their expected to dig through - do they have tungsten carbide or some other equivalently hard substance to make their tool-tips from? The depth of oceans is important too.  But why  wouldn't they just use boats in the first place?

Comment: How deep are these tunnels? I think the food system is more critical here than the physical space for the tunnels. There are lots of tunnels in Hawaii, but no one lives in them because there are no food resources available in tunnels. There's a huge investment to build a non-natural tunnel system, which is why people only build tunnel systems in extraordinary circumstances (avoiding major external threats + easy mining in soft materials). Even nuclear bunkers only have transient inhabitants. You still need surface farm land.

Comment: It is kind of hard to say since it is not a static world, but I guess they started digging since their version of stone age,'now' they are actually a good bit ahead of our tech. They advance pretty fast. @ARogueAnt.

Comment: Well, when they had less tech they planted crops on the surface. Then as they improved their technology, they moved them inside to get artificial sunlight.@DWKraus

Comment: Please edit your question to include clarifications and relevant details.

Comment: I agree with @Otkin, please [edit] your question and add all the details you've mentioned in comments. Editing your question will automatically place it in the reopen review queue. As a habit, never rely on comments for details. Only the body of your question counts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your goal is *bedrock***

I'm going to make an assumption: that your Piinokiins are natural miners. They know how to shore up walls and ceilings and they know how to, at least basically, seal cracks and remove excess water. This is a necessity — because [water is *everywhere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine_dewatering) (not just under oceans).

If we accept that assumption, then the next step is achieving suspension-of-disbelief. Here's an example:

> Yes, there are, if we are to credit a number of
> reports, such tunnels [ancient tunnels]. Not only that – but maps also, that track some of
> these long forgotten tunnels not only beneath the
> earth, but under the sea.
>
> You may discover one running from Spain to Morocco.
> Even some locals will admit that.
>
> But you will probably agree those which penetrate
> under the larger Atlantic and Pacific Oceans would
> be more intriguing. (See Dead Men’s Secrets, ch.19, items 22,37,47,50,
> 64,68,69 and p.205) ([Source](https://b-c-ing-u.com/featured-articles/ancient-tunnels-under-the-sea-tunnels-under-the-ocean-really/))

Whether there's evidence or not of ancient under-the-ocean tunnels isn't the reason I posted that little bit of schlock. If they really existed, the author would make tons more money taking people on tours than he ever would selling books — but what he's trying to do is sell books (five of them, in fact!). What he's relying on is the reader's willingness to suspend their disbelief (I especially like the part where he pitches the idea that they were made with lazers[sic] or electron beams... Atlantis, anyone?).

**So how do we suspend disbelief?**

I'm pitching *bedrock.* If your Piinokiins are master hard-rock miners, then they can dig deep enough to avoid the entire ocean inundating their tunnels. Dig deep enough, and the Earth is "believably" solid (a miner will politely cough at that statement, but remember — suspension of disbelief). Deep enough down, it doesn't matter what's on the surface.

**Let's leave you with some of the realities of mining**

To make the answer somewhat complete, let's leave you with some realities of mining that can be used to complicate your story.

- Air is a huge thing. Getting air into (and the CO2 from breathing creatures out of) tunnels and underground spaces that are even a fraction of the size of what you're talking about is massively non-trivial. Some of it could be explained away with vast underground plant life converting CO2 to O2, but in real mining, air pumps are required.
- Water is also a huge thing, both getting it into the mines for controlled mining purposes and getting it out. A one-inch pipe of water extending only 1,000 feet underground has a bottom water pressure of about 429 psi. Water must usually be brought in and taken out in stages to keep the pressure within controllable limits.
- State and/or continent-spanning underground living space would be subject to every whim of earthquakes. On the surface, we just get shaken around or maybe a big hole forms — but underground things collapse, fill with dust (at best) or gas (at worst) such as the sulfur-laden fumes of exposed magma.
- Finally, I'll leave you with air blasts. I used to live in northern Idaho's Silver Valley, where lots of hard-rock mining takes place. An air blast occurs when a big chunk of rock suddenly shifts, rapidly changing the geometry of the tunnel. If you're thinking of something like the piston in your car moving to its exhaust position, you're on the right track. The result is a compression blast of air that can be heard (and sometimes felt) for tens of miles from the mine opening. It kills miners. Our living Earth sometimes shrugs its proverbial shoulders, just to remind humanity of how trivial it really is.

Answer (score 4):

**Use a volcanic island arc.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_arc

[image: aleutians]

[source](https://wilderness.net/visit-wilderness/?ID=5)

Probably your subterranean large high school people should not live in the Florida Keys.  The soil is sandy and the islands are barely above sea level.  It will be wet downstairs.

Giant islands like Australia or Greenland might as well be continents.

But if you want islands where the ocean is in view wherever you are, and that are good for dry underground bunktresses, you could use the islands of a volcanic island arc.  Depicted: the Aleutian islands off Alaska.  Hawaii is another example.  Especially if they are active volcanoes, the islands will have lots of high elevation land well up out of the water for you people to tunnel into.

Also there is the prospect of hot lava - the Tabasco sauce of any low fantasy endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the population size. Both islands and continents would work within the parameters you set. The smaller Bunktresses could be on Islands, but the larger the population the more space you need. You may want to take into account crust thickness and the weight of these 'Bunktresses'. As, too many holes and caverns close together may weaken the structural integrity around them, unless it's reinforced.

Islands can be pretty large, the largest 'island' on Earth is Greenland. I put a size comparison to the US State of Texas below.
[image]
[https://www.mylifeelsewhere.com/country-size-comparison/greenland/texas-usa#:~:text=Greenland%20is%20about%203.2%20times,Greenland%20219%25%20larger%20than%20Texas](https://www.mylifeelsewhere.com/country-size-comparison/greenland/texas-usa#:%7E:text=Greenland%20is%20about%203.2%20times,Greenland%20219%25%20larger%20than%20Texas).

One thing to keep in mind is sinkholes. Sinkholes occur when an empty space below ground (eroded away naturally, or in a man-made cavern) cannot support the ground above. This can cause the land above to cave in.
https://nisar.jpl.nasa.gov/system/documents/files/2_NISAR_Applications_Sinkholes1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Digging tunnels underground, with the tunnels being under sea level, is
**exactly** as difficult as digging tunnels on dry land, with the tunnels being below the local water table level.

What matters is the water pressure, i.e. how far below the water (table) level your tunnel is.
Also relevant is what material your tunnel is made in. What sort of rock, presence of sealing clays, cracks, etc.
And most relevant, what technology and tools do you have available to remove the *inevitable* water seepage into your tunnels.

The only difference is that when digging from an island, there is a slightly greater chance that sideways digging will encounter a large aquifer.

But relevant to this question:
The answers to these problems are all *exactly* the same whether you are in the middle of a continent, or on a tiny island out at sea.

Comment: I guess when you are under land, you can just dig up to reach the surface, for ventilation and/or evacuation purposes. When you are under water, the water comes in.

Answer (score 3):

### At What Price?

My sense is that there is a compelling reason why these folks want to dwell as deep and as sheltered as they possibly can be. Given their tech level (stated in comments) I'm guessing that nuclear war or a similar major external threat are motivators to the digging (thus the bunker/fortress concept, both military terms). But mostly, the people really just prefer living underground.

For a reasonably high-tech civilization, with artificial lighting and a strong desire to live underground (but with access to the surface if needed), they can live anywhere they want to, provided they use enough engineering and are willing to put in the effort.

Water can be pumped out, walls and barriers can be constructed to block water if it's an issue, food can be generated in underground farms, and even mass transit (huge elevators and/or subways) can be built everywhere. In fact, due to the support of rock in all directions, you are likely going to be able to achieve higher population densities with carefully constructed cities than places like New York. After all, the buildings can always keep going deeper until the heat gets too unsustainable (and even then, with access to the surface you'll be able to vent heat and use it for geothermal energy). This is not really that different from the idea of underwater domed cities, but without a single dome. You could even build UNDER the sea, but then surface access becomes more difficult. But you can vent CO2 and generate O2 and water from sea water given enough power.

So your people will be able to overcome ANY obstacle short of severe fault zones with enough engineering (and nuclear bunkers like NORAD are built to withstand massive earthquakes and near-direct hits by massive atomic weapons, so even this can be overcome).

The problem is that each effort you make costs a ton of effort/money. Building shallowly or on the surface or in soft materials or in places with favorable water tables is going to be cheap. Cut-and-cover tunnels built shallowly on the surface, then covered over with dirt will be vastly less expensive than deep tunnels, and will be able to be placed almost anywhere. The state that builds in the cheapest way, with the least amount of effort, will outcompete their neighbors for resources, population growth, and so on. A smelting plant (for example) venting pollutants into the air vs. one trying to keep everything self-contained will be cheap. A tunnel in soft, dry rock will go twice as far, twice as fast.

So your civilization will be constantly incentivized (like ours) to build as cheaply and quickly as possible. The easy constructs will be built first, and the income generated from these areas will be used to slowly dig into deeper, harder, wetter, or more hazardous areas. If such places are considered more desirable, then the rich and powerful, the upper crust and elites will live in the most sheltered places, while the poor are forced to dwell on or near the surface.

In the event of a war, the rich and powerful will live, while the poor die. But as soon as the war is over, those same areas that were destroyed will be resettled in order to grow the GDP of their states. After all, how else can you raise the money to build more deep bunkers, which proved themselves so safe?